# Intellij Idea. Once Spring MVC context is autodetected, it's location cannot be changed

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

Here is my problem:
Initially I placed `spring-servlet.xml` in the root of my WEB-INF folder.
Then "MVC" was autodetected and everything went fine (look at first screen).

Then I wanted to move my `spring-servlet.xml` to config folder.
I moved it and all the bindings were lost, and the context was pointing in the previous location (see second screen). 
If I delete "MVC spring servlet context" and click "Apply", it would not be actually deleted (if I'll go back after deleting it will still be there).

I think I need to point file location manually, but I don't know how to do it in Intellij.

How to solve this problem?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe as per the default configuration of Spring MVC, It pick the dispatcher-servlet file directly from WEB-INF. But if you want to provide the custom location, You can use `<init-param>` in for dispatcherServlet in web.xml and provide the custom location of xml file.
Eg.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Another way is to use Spring ContextLoaderListner in web.xml and giving xml file as `<context-param>` 
Eg.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```